# why do I need a constructor function?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    int i;
};

int main() {
  const A aa;  //This is wrong, I can't compile it! The implicitly-defined constructor does not initialize ‘int A::i’
}
```

when I use

```
class A {
public:
  A() {}
  int i;
};
```

this is ok! I can compile it! why I can't compile it when I use the implicitly-defined constructor?

Comment: You are not declaring any constructor here.

Comment: What do you mean, "this is ok"? Your constructor doesn't initialise `i` either.

Comment: I mean that I can compile it;

Comment: So to be clear, you're asking why you get a compiler error if you don't define a constructor, but not if you define one that doesn't initialise the value?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work?" How do you determine whether it works? What did you expect? What actually happened?

Answer (score 10):

> why the implicit-defined constructor does not work?

It does work, but one of the language rules is that it can't be used to initialise a `const` object unless it initialises all the members; and it doesn't initialise members with trivial types like `int`. That usually makes sense, since being `const` there's no way to give them a value later.

<sub>(That's a slight simplification; see the comments for chapter and verse from the language standard.)</sub>

If you define your own constructor, then you're saying that you know what you're doing and don't want that member initialised. The compiler will let you use that even for a `const` object.

If you want to set it to zero, then you could value-initialise the object:

```
const A aa {};    // C++11 or later
const A aa = A(); // historic C++
```

If you want to set it to another value, or set it to zero without the user having to specify value-initialisation, then you'll need a constructor that initialises the member:

```
A() : i(whatever) {}
```

Comment: _"it can't be used to initialise a const object unless it initialises all the members"_ That's not the rule, the rule is: _"If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a const-qualified type `T`, `T` shall be a class type with a user-provided default constructor."_  Maybe you're thinking of `constexpr` constructors.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Or maybe I'm simplifying the rule because I can't be bothered to quote chapter and verse for every answer. But thanks for the correction.

Comment: Actually, there's an open DR which proposes to change it to what you said, so you'll be right soon :) http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#253

Answer (score 9):

> why the implicit-defined constructor does not work?

Because the C++ standard says so:

**[dcl.init]** paragraph 7:
*If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a const-qualified type `T`, `T` shall be a class type with a user-provided default constructor.*

This ensures that you don't create a `const` object containing uninitialized data that cannot be initialized later.

To initialize a const-qualified object you need to have a user-provided default constructor or use an initialiser:

```
const A aa = A();
```

Here the object `aa` is initialized with the expression `A()` which is a value-initialized object. You can value-initialize a class type without a default constructor, because value-initialization will set values to zero if there is no default constructor for the type.

However, the rule in the standard is too strict, as it forbids using implicitly-defined constructors even when there are no data members or all data members have sensible default constructors, so there is a defect report against the standard proposing to change it, see [issue 253](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#253).

Answer (score 2):

You don't state what compiler you're using.  I've tried this with VS2012 and get a warning [C4269](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/424ea098%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

The reason this is a problem is because `aa` is `const`.  Because you haven't defined a constructor a default one is used and so `i` can be anything.  It also cannot be changed (because `aa` is const).

If you define a constructor, it is assumed that you are happy with the initialization of `i`.  Although, in this case you haven't actually changed the behaviour.

From this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/424ea098%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> Since this instance of the class is generated on the stack, the initial value of m_data can be anything. Also, since it is a const instance, the value of m_data can never be changed.

Comment: my compiler  g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3

Answer (score 0):

Because `i` is not initialized.

```
class A 
{ 
    public:
    A()
    {
        i =0;
    }
    int i;
};
```

"Implicit constructor" means a constructor generated for you automatically and generates an error because it realizes it is not able to initialize the value of `i`. This can be a no-args constructor, a copy constructor or (as of C++11) a move constructor.

Answer (score 0):

> why the implicit-defined constructor does not work?

It works just fine, but it does not decide what your default values are implicitly (and as such, it only calls default constructors for it's members, but not for POD types).

If you want the constructor to initialize your members with certain values you have to explicitly write that (i.e. add a default constructor explicitly).

Making a default (implicit) constructor initialize POD members with a chosen value (like zero for example) would add extra computing cycles (and slow your program down) when you don't need that. C++ is designed to behave as if you (the programmer) know what you are doing (i.e. if you do not initialize your members explicitly, the compiler assumes you don't care what default value you get).